# In R, output the variable of a column into a single row in a file?

Tags: r

This is the dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame("Identifier" = sample(100001:100010, 6, replace = F), 
               y = sample(rnorm(10), 6, replace = T), 
               z = sample(rnorm(10), 6, replace = T))
```

When i want to output some of the information, save it into a single file, i use

```
write(c(nrow(df1), 2, 1), file="GSE49995_cls.txt", sep = "\t")
write(df1$y, file="GSE49995_cls.txt", append = T, sep = "\t")
write(c("df1$y","df1$x"), file="GSE49995_cls.txt", append = T, sep = "\t")
```

when I open the file, GSE49995_cls.txt,

```
6 2 1
1.226647    -0.3621273  0.5439381   -1.16689    -0.3621273
-0.3621273
df1$y
df1$x
```

But I want my output in this way

```
6 2 1
1.226647    -0.3621273  0.5439381   -1.16689    -0.3621273   -0.3621273
df1$y   df1$x
```

Every word is separated by tab space. Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the `ncolumns` argument of `write()`, which is by default set to

```
ncolumns = if (is.character(x)) 1 else 5
```

So your first two calls are going to 5, and hence the second wraps to a second line.  And your third call goes to 1 because it's a character, and hence wraps to a second line.  Changing the first to `length(df1$y)` and the second to `2` will solve the problem.

```
f <- "GSE49995_cls.txt"
write(c(nrow(df1), 2, 1), file = f, sep = "\t")
write(df1$y, file = f, ncolumns = length(df1$y), append = TRUE, sep = "\t")
write(c("df1$y","df1$x"), file = f, ncolumns = 2, append = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

After running this code, I get a file `GSE49995_cls.txt` that looks like the following.

```
6   2   1   
0.7413901   0.9874447   -0.2382336  -0.9549439  0.9874447   -0.5963106  
df1$x   df1$y
```

Alternatively, you could use `cat()` and not have to worry about this at all.

```
cat(c(nrow(df1), 2, 1), "\n", sep = "\t", file = f)
cat(df1$y, "\n", sep = "\t", file = f, append = TRUE)
cat(c("df1$x", "df1$y"), "\n", sep = "\t", file = f, append = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. By the way, why the first line don't need to add anything yet it will save as a single row?

Comment: @pill45 - Because you pass it a vector of length 3, which is not character.  So `ncolumns = 5`, but since you don't have 5, you have 3, it looks how you want it to look.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that c("df1$y","df1$x") is not a vector of length 2?

Comment: @pill45 - Yes, but it is a character vector, which will default to 1 so we have to change it.  It's a bit confusing and probably not ideal, I know :)